# how to get a key in this json with javascript

Tags: javascript

i have this json, that is the response from a server, i need extract the data in this json or modify it, for generate an object to use in other function that generate a graphic with this object

```
{
"data1": "{ \"y\": 51.08, \"label\": \"Chrome\" }, { \"y\": 27.34, \"label\": \"Internet Explorer\" }, { \"y\": 10.62, \"label\": \"Firefox\" }, { \"y\": 5.02, \"label\": \"Microsoft Edge\" }, { \"y\": 4.07, \"label\": \"Safari\" }, { \"y\": 1.22, \"label\": \"Opera\" }, { \"y\": 0.44, \"label\": \"Others\" }"
}

var event = JSON.parse(xhr.response);

console.log(event);

var dataGraph = Array(event['data1']);

let dati = Object.assign({},dataGraph);

const keys = Object.keys(dati);

for (const key of keys) {

    console.log(key)

}
console.log(datito)
```

i need generate an object in this way

```
{ "y": 51.08, "label": "Chrome" }, { "y": 27.34, "label": "Internet Explorer" }, { "y": 10.62, "label": "Firefox" }, { "y": 5.02, "label": "Microsoft Edge" }, { "y": 4.07, "label": "Safari" }, { "y": 1.22, "label": "Opera" }, { "y": 0.44, "label": "Others" }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using `responseText` instead of `response`.

```
var event = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);

console.log(event.data1);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
split and join
```

```js
var a={
"data1": "{ \"y\": 51.08, \"label\": \"Chrome\" }, { \"y\": 27.34, \"label\": \"Internet Explorer\" }, { \"y\": 10.62, \"label\": \"Firefox\" }, { \"y\": 5.02, \"label\": \"Microsoft Edge\" }, { \"y\": 4.07, \"label\": \"Safari\" }, { \"y\": 1.22, \"label\": \"Opera\" }, { \"y\": 0.44, \"label\": \"Others\" }"
}
console.log(a.data1.split('\\').join(''))
```